# How to check certificate and key pair created by CSP or PKCS?

Tags: c, rsacryptoserviceprovider, pkcs#11

I have a problem with keypair and certificate generate in token using csp or pkcs, and i must to distict this then i want to know 
"How to check certificate and key pair created by CSP or PKCS ??".

Answer (score 1):

You should check their respective API as the first step.

For PKCS, you should read PKCS11 standard as mentioned on: http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133

This API interface will contains the method to check on the certificate.

Take note that in general, CSP is used by only Microsoft Product, while PKCS is used by the other software vendors.